# How to merge only specific SVN revision?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I have java file  under branch_A which is at SVN version 100.

1. Modified this file and checked it in.  SVN version becomes 101
2. Now i modified the file again . Version becomes 102.

Now i need to merge the only SVN revision 102 not revision 101 to another branch. If i merge it through tortoise SVN or subclipse, How can i merge the 
changes under specific revision only  not the previous revision i.e. 101 ?

Is it possible though SVN merge or i need to do it manually ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to run a [cherrypick merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.cherrypicking). Read [TortoiseSVN Manual | Merging](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html#tsvn-dug-merge-options) for the instructions specific to TSVN client.